# Customizable filtering on a stream

Tags: c#, functional-programming, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I need to configure a list of filters on a stream.

The stream initially doesn't have any filter, but during time it has a list of active filters.

Each filter will have a strict validity period.

A test case follows:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

var input = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0200.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0300.Ms(), '2'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0400.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0600.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0700.Ms(), '5'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0800.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0900.Ms(), 'C') );

// filters
// A between 70ms -> 550ms
// B between 330ms -> 400ms 
// modeled as a string observable where:
// first word is the char to filter
// second word are the msecs duration of the filter

var filters = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0070.Ms(), "A 480"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0330.Ms(), "B 70")
);

var expected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0300.Ms(), '2'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0600.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0700.Ms(), '5'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0800.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0900.Ms(), 'C') );
```

Can you suggest me which is the best Rx-solution to do this?

p.s.: I am using the following extension method

```
public static class TickExtensions
{
    public static long Ms(this int ms)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms).Ticks;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. I think `Ms()` should return a long. `filters` looks like it should be a `CreateColdObservable<string>`.

Comment: @LeeCampbell right, I fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your input should look like this:

```
var input = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0200.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0300.Ms(), '2'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0400.Ms(), 'B'), //You forgot this line
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0600.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0700.Ms(), '5'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0800.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0900.Ms(), 'C'));
```

Also, as @LeeCampbell mentioned, your `Ms` extension method should return type `long`, not `TimeSpan`.

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
 var activeFilters = filters
    .Select(s => s.Split(' '))
    .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s[0][0], TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.Parse(s[1]))))
    .Select(t => Observable.Timer(t.Item2, scheduler).Select(_ => t.Item1).StartWith(t.Item1))
    .MergeCombineLatest(true)
    .StartWith(new List<char>());

var output = activeFilters.Publish(_activeFilters => 
        input.Join(_activeFilters,
            _ => Observable.Return(1),
            t => _activeFilters,
            (c, filterList) => Tuple.Create(c, filterList)
        )
    )
    .Where(t => !t.Item2.Contains(t.Item1))
    .Select(t => t.Item1);

var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<char>();
output.Subscribe(observer);
scheduler.Start();

ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
    expected.Messages,
    observer.Messages);
```

`activeFilters` is an observable that emits a list of characters currently under filter. When the actively-filtered list changes, `activeFilters` emits a new List. Note that since the same character can have multiple filters, the list is not necessarily unique.

Once you can figure out at any given time which filters are active, you can join that list to the input.

The code requires this extension method, which uses the System.Collections.Immutable Nuget package:

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> MergeCombineLatest<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> outer, bool removeCompleted)
{
    return outer
        .SelectMany((inner, i) => inner
            .Materialize()
            .SelectMany(nt => nt.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext
                ? Observable.Return(Tuple.Create(i, nt.Value, true))
                : nt.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted
                    ? removeCompleted
                        ? Observable.Return(Tuple.Create(i, default(T), false))
                        : Observable.Empty<Tuple<int, T, bool>>()
                    : Observable.Throw<Tuple<int, T, bool>>(nt.Exception)
            )
        )
        .Scan(ImmutableDictionary<int, T>.Empty, (dict, t) => t.Item3 ? dict.SetItem(t.Item1, t.Item2) : dict.Remove(t.Item1))
        .Select(dict => dict.Values.ToList());
}
```

`MergeCombineLatest` takes an observable of observables and emits a list of the latest values from each of the child observables. If the `removeCompleted` is true, then when a child observable completes, the list shrinks by one. If `removeCompleted` is false, then the last value stays in the list and successive lists forever.

If there's some friendlier way of doing this, I would be much obliged.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer!! I will check it out ASAP.

Comment: Inspired from your solution I ended up with the following one.
https://gist.github.com/zpul/fcc82cb0e963ab69ebf7ae8fc7d95b2f
What do you think about it?

Comment: The great thing about Rx (or any functional code) is that it allows us to avoid side-effects/state problems, as well as thread-safety issues. `List<T>` is not thread-safe. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Anchor_10. Your code could have problems if you try to add/remove a filter at the same time, as well as some other function accidentally tampering with the `excludeFilters` variable.

Comment: Given all that, it seems to work. I would prefer a more purely functional solution.